# Gradle exclude group from dependant subproject

Tags: java, gradle, dependency-management

Given a gradle project A having a dependency on project B (no common parent)

```
compile project('B'){
    exclude group: 'org.slf4j'
}
```

**how do we exclude transitive dependency group from a project we depend upon?** (this piece of script will fail as there is no `exclude` for `compile projet(..)`)

and more general question : **is there an elegant way to exclude a particular group from all dependancies except if its a first level dependency?**

for example we may have a bunch of libraries, and each may declare its logging environment, but by excluding all known groups of `slf4j`, its implementations and declaring specific version, we would ensure we don't have any version conflicts and would control version on module level.

Comment: It should work with `compile(project('B')) { exclude group: 'org.slf4j' }`. Note the double parens. Have you tried?

Comment: Oh so the braces fixed that one thank you, could you suggest something for the general question? because there are many dependencies, would be cool to just exclude from all of them these groups and only specify the exact version we want...

Comment: if the second question is not clear i can try to show some sample script and update the question... just let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example from the Gradle documentation of how to exclude a transitive dependency (I guess that is what you meant by "except if its a first level dependency") on project level:

```
configurations {
    compile.exclude module: 'commons'
    all*.exclude group: 'org.gradle.test.excludes', module: 'reports'
}
```

See *52.4.7. Excluding transitive dependencies* [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html)

You can either specify the dependency directly with the desired version or use a forced version [resolution strategy](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/ResolutionStrategy.html#force(java.lang.Object...))

Comment: yes but you see i want to add that very excluded dependency but with my specified version... just exclude from everywhere and add this...

Comment: You can either specify the dependency directly with the desired version or use a forced version resolution strategy: https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/ResolutionStrategy.html#force(java.lang.Object...)

Comment: Please add this comment to answer, as soon as i try it i'll accept the answer, just to make sure it works :)